# Method accepting two different types as parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, overloading

**Requirement**:-

In getDetails method, if object B of type **Customclass** is passed, then we are calling getStatus method which is taking **Customclass** as argument. 
Now, we need to make the argument which can take both **string**/ **customclass** type,

```
    so if it is string, then we are directly getting the value so need not to call getStatus method
    And if it of type **customclass**, then we need to invoke getStatus
```

In my existing project, we are invoking **getDetails** from multiple places and getDetails is lengthy method, **so overloading is too costly which will make code repetition**

Please suggest some other ways

I have code something like similar below:-

```
    getDetails(Strig a, Customclass B) {
      //lengthy calculation long method
      String status = getStatus(B)
     //lengthy calculation long method
   }
```

Which I want to make it like below:-

```
   getDetails(Strig a, Customclass B || String B) {
           //lengthy calculation long method
           String status;
            If(B of type String) {
              status = B;
            } else {

               status = getStatus(B)
            }
           //lengthy calculation long method
   }
```

Comment: You can create an custom class as an Enum, in the case you can cover both scenarios.

Comment: how you are suggesting? will it require me to chage only at one place or do I Need to repeat the code everywhere I am invoking it? Any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

create two method getdetails:

getDetails(Strig a, Customclass B)

getDetails(Strig a, String B)

Comment: as I mentioned in my post as well In my existing project, we are invoking getDetails from multiple places and getDetails is lengthy method so overloading is too costly which will make code repetition

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, I would normally achieve it with overloading the method

```
getDetails(String a, Customclass B) {
    //lengthy calculation long method
    String status = getStatus(B)
    //lengthy calculation long method
}

getDetails(String a, String B) {
    String status = B
}
```

In overloading, you provide 2 or more methods that have different parameter requirements. Then when you call the method, java determines which method to call, based on the types of the parameters you pass in.

Comment: as I mentioned in my post as well In my existing project, we are invoking getDetails from multiple places and getDetails is lengthy method so overloading is too costly which will make code repetition

Comment: @sgiowtswpjtwhhjtkw You can have one overload delegate to the other or extract the common code out into another, private method...

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ICustomInterface {
    //some code if needed
}

class StringWrapper implements ICustomInterface {
    private String value;

    public StringWrapper(String str) {
        this.value = str;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class CustomClass implements ICustomInterface {
    //some code

    public static void getDetails(String a, ICustomInterface b) {
        if (b instanceof CustomClass) {
            System.out.println("Custom class");
            //some code
        } else if (b instanceof StringWrapper) {
            System.out.println(((StringWrapper) b).getValue());
            //some code
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass();
        CustomClass.getDetails("first case", customClass);
        CustomClass.getDetails("second case", new StringWrapper("String"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wa thinking of that then again Object b, which is at the top heirrchy, We shouldnot use it

Comment: Then wrap that String into some class and let them both to implement some interface, so your parameters will look like (String a, ISomeInterface b), then use conditions with instanceof.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading might be possible *without duplication*, by delegating the call from one to the other:

```
getDetails(String a, Customclass B) {
    getDetails(a, getStatus(B));
}

getDetails(String a, String status) {
    // just keep this method
}

String getStatus(Customclass object) {
    // I guess you have this one already
}
```

The call in line 2 is not recursion or anything, but is actually a call to the method of line 5.

Comment: Nobody wants to have code duplication in overloaded methods. That's why the common approach is to only have one of the overloaded methods do the actual work (in your case, the one taking the status string), and have the other methods just translate their arguments and forward them to the real method

Comment: If you have any more questions, just let me know

Comment: what you are suggesting for the implementation of String getStatus(Customclass object) {
    // I guess you have this one already
}

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but How about something as simple as this?

```
getDetails(Sting a, Object b) {
    if (b instanceof Customclass) {
        Customclass customer = (Customclass) b;
        // Here you can use a customer
    } else if (b instanceof String) {
        // Here you can use string
    }
}
```